# autojump bug - /usr/bin/env: ‘python333333’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, zsh

While running cd, i always get a message like this, and i observed the number of 3's keep increasing as i close the terminal and reopen it.

I tried uninstalling autojump and installing it again, and that cleared it for a moment, but after i opened another terminal, the error starts popping up, and increasing the number of 3s everytime i reopen another terminal, and autojump stops working.

Comment: Did you add anything to `.zshrc` to change `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` by any chance?

Comment: I only have a simple alias that refer to python 3 like py, I remove the aliases I had but the issue still occurred

Comment: Something is modifying the first line of the python script.  Does [this](https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/577) jog your memory, specifically this suggestion: `sed -i "s/\#\!\/usr\/bin\/env\ python/\#\!\/usr\/bin\/env\ python3/" ~/.autojump/bin/autojump`

Comment: yes I added this, is this the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of a script tells the computer what language it is written in. Following a suggestion at https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/577, you are running a `sed` command designed to edit the first line of `autojump` from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

by appending a `3`.  However, it wasn't designed to check it hadn't already been run, so it keeps adding more and more of them.

Only run it once.  However, changing the command from:

```
sed -i "s/\#\!\/usr\/bin\/env\ python/\#\!\/usr\/bin\/env\ python3/" ~/.autojump/bin/autojump
```

to:

```
sed -i "s/\#\!\/usr\/bin\/env\ python$/\#\!\/usr\/bin\/env\ python3/" ~/.autojump/bin/autojump
```

will ensure it only edits it once. The `$` requires there is nothing already after the `python`.